# how to use include straight in define in php

Tags: php, include

I want to use include straight in define in php

for e.g.

```
<?php define('panel' , 'include "../panel/admin.php";'); //in a saperate php page ?>
```

and include this file

Now I want use

`<?php panel ?> //in another page`

Comment: `<?php echo panel ?>` will be better. Do you have any error ?

Comment: nothing . echo just show include "../panel/admin.php";

Comment: The second parameter can only be a scalar value  (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL). In php 7 array values are also accepted.

Comment: i know but what is the solotion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mohade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548802/4198099) is correct.

However you can do the same with your existing code by below way.

```
 define('panel' , 'include "/panel/admin.php";'); 

 eval(panel); // eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @amin: Welcome :) Please accept the useful answer So future visitors can find it as useful.

Comment: i am going to choise the best answer to accept :) please wait ;)

Answer (score 8):

you cant use include() in define

you must do this

```
<?php define("panel" , "../panel/admin.php"); ?>
```

and then include it

```
<?php 

include(panel);

 ?>
```